# A dark fantasy book with warring kingdoms, blue soulless people, magic costs souls

Tags: story-identification

This book I read in maybe 98-2002, so from around that era. It focused on a prince and his group of friends in a medieval setting.

The land is magical and anyone can summon clothing or shelter temporarily as a jet black material. However, something happens to cause an increased amount of use of this power, and people start being born with discoloured skin and 'no soul' they age quickly and barbaric and conscience-less, and quickly form their own kingdom and eventually go to war with the original kingdom.

I think the book culminates in a fight between the prince and the leader of the enemy kingdom, the prince's son. The son knows that he is likely to die in the fires surrounding the battle, but knows he can summon a fireproof cloak to protect him, but he had a vision in which summoning things cost the souls of your forebears, and knows if he does it it will extinguish his fathers soul.

I bought this in a post office in New Zealand if that helps any.